# unicorn request queuing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, unicorn

We just migrated from passenger to unicorn to host few rails apps.
Everything works great but we notice via New Relic that request are queuing between 100 and 300ms.

Here's the graph :

[image]

I have no idea where this is coming from here's our unicorn conf :

```
current_path = '/data/actor/current'
shared_path = '/data/actor/shared'
shared_bundler_gems_path = "/data/actor/shared/bundled_gems"
working_directory '/data/actor/current/'

worker_processes 6

listen '/var/run/engineyard/unicorn_actor.sock', :backlog => 1024

timeout 60

pid "/var/run/engineyard/unicorn_actor.pid"

logger Logger.new("log/unicorn.log")

stderr_path "log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "log/unicorn.stdout.log"

preload_app true

if GC.respond_to?(:copy_on_write_friendly=)
  GC.copy_on_write_friendly = true
end

before_fork do |server, worker|
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  end

  old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"

  if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
    begin
      sig = (worker.nr + 1) >= server.worker_processes ? :TERM : :TTOU
      Process.kill(sig, File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
      # someone else did our job for us
    end
  end
  sleep 1
end

if defined?(Bundler.settings)
  before_exec do |server|
    paths = (ENV["PATH"] || "").split(File::PATH_SEPARATOR)
    paths.unshift "#{shared_bundler_gems_path}/bin"
    ENV["PATH"] = paths.uniq.join(File::PATH_SEPARATOR)

    ENV['GEM_HOME'] = ENV['GEM_PATH'] = shared_bundler_gems_path
    ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = "#{current_path}/Gemfile"
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  worker_pid = File.join(File.dirname(server.config[:pid]), "unicorn_worker_actor_#{worker.nr$
  File.open(worker_pid, "w") { |f| f.puts Process.pid }
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end

end
```

our nginx.conf :

```
user deploy deploy;
worker_processes 6;

worker_rlimit_nofile 10240;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 8192;
  use epoll;
}

http {

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

  default_type application/octet-stream;

  log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                  '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  sendfile on;

  tcp_nopush        on;

  server_names_hash_bucket_size  128;

  if_modified_since before;
  gzip              on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_comp_level   2;
  gzip_proxied      any;
  gzip_buffers      16 8k;
  gzip_types        application/json text/plain text/html text/css application/x-javascript t$
  # gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

  # Allow custom settings to be added to the http block
  include /etc/nginx/http-custom.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/stack.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/servers/*.conf;
}
```

and our app specific nginx conf :

```
upstream upstream_actor_ssl {
  server unix:/var/run/engineyard/unicorn_actor.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 443;

  server_name letitcast.com;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/letitcast.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/letitcast.key;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

  client_max_body_size 100M;

  root /data/actor/current/public;

  access_log /var/log/engineyard/nginx/actor.access.log main;
  error_log /var/log/engineyard/nginx/actor.error.log notice;

  location @app_actor {
    include /etc/nginx/common/proxy.conf;
    proxy_pass http://upstream_actor_ssl;
  }

  include /etc/nginx/servers/actor/custom.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/servers/actor/custom.ssl.conf;

  if ($request_filename ~* \.(css|jpg|gif|png)$) {
    break;
  }

  location ~ ^/(images|javascripts|stylesheets)/ {
    expires 10y;
  }

  error_page 404 /404.html;
  error_page 500 502 504 /500.html;
  error_page 503 /system/maintenance.html;

  location = /system/maintenance.html { }

  location / {
    if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) { return 503; }

    try_files  $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @app_actor;
  }

  include /etc/nginx/servers/actor/custom.locations.conf;
}
```

We are not under heavy load so I don't understand why requests are stuck in the queue.
As specified in the unicorn conf, we have 6 unicorn workers.

Any idea where this could be coming from ?

Cheers

**EDIT:**

Average requests per minute: about 15 most of the time, more than 300 in peeks but we didn't experienced one since the migration.
CPU Load average: 0.2-0.3

I tried with 8 workers, it didn't change anything.

I've also used [raindrops](http://raindrops.bogomips.org/) to look what unicorn workers were up to.

Here's the ruby script :

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

# this is used to show or watch the number of active and queued
# connections on any listener socket from the command line

require 'raindrops'
require 'optparse'
require 'ipaddr'
usage = "Usage: #$0 [-d delay] ADDR..."
ARGV.size > 0 or abort usage
delay = false

# "normal" exits when driven on the command-line
trap(:INT) { exit 130 }
trap(:PIPE) { exit 0 }

opts = OptionParser.new('', 24, '  ') do |opts|
  opts.banner = usage
  opts.on('-d', '--delay=delay') { |nr| delay = nr.to_i }
  opts.parse! ARGV
end

socks = []
ARGV.each do |f|
  if !File.exists?(f)
    puts "#{f} not found"
    next
  end

  if !File.socket?(f)
    puts "#{f} ain't a socket"
    next
  end

  socks << f
end

fmt = "% -50s % 10u % 10u\n"
printf fmt.tr('u','s'), *%w(address active queued)

begin
  stats = Raindrops::Linux.unix_listener_stats(socks)
  stats.each do |addr,stats| 
    if stats.queued.to_i > 0
      printf fmt, addr, stats.active, stats.queued
    end
  end
end while delay && sleep(delay)
```

How i've launched it :

```
./linux-tcp-listener-stats.rb -d 0.1 /var/run/engineyard/unicorn_actor.sock
```

So it basically check every 1/10s if there are requests in the queue and if there are it outputs :

**the socket** | **the number of requests being processed** | **the number of requests in the queue**

Here's a gist of the result :

https://gist.github.com/f9c9e5209fbbfc611cb1

**EDIT2:**

I tried to reduce the number of nginx workers to one last night but it didn't change anything.

For information we are hosted on Engine Yard and have a High-CPU Medium Instance 1.7 GB of memory, 5 EC2 Compute Units (2 virtual cores with 2.5 EC2 Compute Units each)

We host 4 rails applications, this one has 6 workers, we have one with 4, one with 2 and another with one. They're all experiencing request queuing since we migrated to unicorn.
I don't know if Passenger was cheating but New Relic didn't log any request queuing when we were using it. We also have a node.js app handling file uploads, a mysql database and 2 redis.

**EDIT 3:**

We're using ruby 1.9.2p290, nginx 1.0.10, unicorn 4.2.1 and newrelic_rpm 3.3.3.
I'll try without newrelic tomorrow and will let you know the results here but for the information we were using passenger with new relic, the same version of ruby and nginx and didnt have any issue.

**EDIT 4:**

I tried to increase the `client_body_buffer_size` and `proxy_buffers` with

`client_body_buffer_size 256k;

proxy_buffers 8 256k;`

But it didn't do the trick.

**EDIT 5:**

We finally figured it out ... drumroll ...
The winner was our SSL cypher. When we changed it to RC4 we saw the request queuing droppping from 100-300ms to 30-100ms.

Comment: Is your actual response time increased over when you were using Passenger, or is it just the New Relic breakdown of what is responsible for the response times that is alarming?

Comment: When we were using passenger we were serving requests in about 120ms, so yes it's the average request time that is alarming. My main question is why are the requests stuck in the queue when we have few requests per minute with 6 unicorn workers ?

Comment: What's the load? How many RPM? Did you do the math (can your 6 workers keep up with the load)? Did you try spawning more unicorn workers?

Comment: I'm curious if this is latency inherent in Unicorn; how long would it take to write a dirt-simple Hello World application that does nearly nothing and could be used to measure the latency of Unicorn at its simplest?

Comment: @sarnold I'll try to find sometime tomorrow to try this

Comment: @Mike: By the way, you don't need a nginx worker for each unicorn worker. IIRC, it is recommended to have one nginx worker per core (and only if you are under load). In your setup one nginx worker is more than enough. 

I wonder, could this affect unicorns somehow?

Comment: @sarnold: Unicorn most certainly isn't slow. In my app 15 workers handle 10-30k rpm with sub-millisecond response time.

Comment: @Sergio: that's encouraging. If Mike's is significantly slower, it might be easier to figure out why on a smaller application. Is this being hosted in a virtualized environment? Are there other jobs on the machine running at higher or real-time priorities?

Comment: @sarnold: his app is running on EngineYard VMs, I assume. Mine - on a dedicated server (not too beefy).

Comment: Just edited the question guys with some more informations about the VM specs and what's hosted on it.

Comment: @Mike Note the caveats [here](http://sirupsen.com/setting-up-unicorn-with-nginx/) and [here](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/PHILOSOPHY.html) about slow clients: `If your application responses are larger than the socket buffer or if you’re handling large requests (uploads), worker processes will also be bottlenecked by the speed of the client connection. You should not allow unicorn to serve clients outside of your local network.` This will, to my understanding, significantly affect your performance tests. If this is useful information, I'll rewrite this as an answer.

Comment: @MrGomez that's why we're using nginx, we don't handle large uploads via unicorn (we're using node).

Comment: @Mike did you ever figure out what was going on? I'm seeing similar times in Request Queuing using unicorn...

Comment: @mike curious - now that RC4 is being deprecated in favor of AES, what are you planning to do?  

Also, in the graph above, our newrelic instance doesn't show queuing - is that the server monitor, or did you have to do something specific in the application monitor to get the queuing data?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've just diagnosed a similar looking New relic graph as being entirely the fault of SSL. Try turning it off. We are seeing 400ms request queuing time, which drops to 20ms without SSL.

Some interesting points on why some SSL providers might be slow: http://blog.cloudflare.com/how-cloudflare-is-making-ssl-fast

Comment: I just added an edit, we figured that out a few months ago.
We didn't  turned it off but changing the cypher made the trick.
I'm accepting your answer anyways.

Comment: Do you terminate SSL/TLS before it hits the upstream? Second question: have you tried to cache SSL/TLS connection on reverse-proxy side?

Comment: @mikhailov Neither, I think. This was a Rails app hosted on Engineyard.

Comment: @MattGibson don't you have a root access to the box?

Comment: @mikhailov Yes, I did, but the project was mothballed and is no longer running.

Answer (score 1):

What version of ruby, unicorn, nginx (shouldn't matter much but worth mentioning) and newrelic_rpm are you using?

Also, I would try running a baseline perf test without newrelic. NewRelic parses the response and there are cases where this can be slow due to the issue with 'rindex' in ruby pre-1.9.3. This is usually only noticeable when you're response is very large and doesn't contain 'body' tags (e.g. AJAX, JSON, etc). I saw an example of this where a 1MB AJAX response was taking 30 seconds for NewRelic to parse.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I replied in EDIT3

Comment: Given that you weren't seeing the issue with Passenger, it's unlikely the NewRelic issue I was referring to.

Comment: I am investigating a similar issue and I have the suspicion that the NewRelic patch for nginx is including the download time of the request from the client, which could explain high "queue" times. Currently I haven't been able to prove that, though...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are buffering the requests from the clients in nginx and then buffering the responses from the unicorns before sending them back to the clients. From your setup it seems that you do (because this is by default), but I will suggest you double check that.

The config to look at is:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_buffering

This is for the buffering of the response from the unicorns. You definitely need it because you don't want to keep unicorns busy sending data to a slow client.

For the buffering of the request from the client I think that you need to look at:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#client_body_buffer_size

I think all this can't explain a delay of 100ms, but I am not familiar with all of your system setup, so it is worth it to have a look at this direction. It seems that your queuing is not caused by a CPU contention, but by some kind of IO blocking.

Comment: I tried with `client_body_buffer_size 256k;` and `proxy_buffers 8 256k;` but it didn't improve.